# Enable HDMI output on 21.10

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I have got problem with NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64 kernel: 5.15.7-051507-generic.
I cannot attach external monitor via HDMI.

After fresh install I made it working by installing 495 driver in performance mode. It worked in that setup for a month but recently stopped.

My laptop has 2 GPUs:

- Intel TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics]
- NVIDIA RTX A2000 Mobile

System is up to date.

Secure Boot is disabled

inxi -G output:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GA107GLM [RTX A2000 Mobile] driver: N/A 
           Device-3: Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 driver: loaded: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (TGL GT1) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2
```

nvidia-smi output:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

prime-select query output:

```
on-demand
```

[additional drivers indicates that 495 is in use - click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpNiu.png)

[NVIDIA settings applet is empty - click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUDkj.png)

nvidia-settings output:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:6505): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:17:52.182: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 14:17:52.185: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 14:17:52.185: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

In desperation I checked Windows 10 - it works there, thus cable, monitor, bios and hardware are fine.

I tried to follow instructions found on the Internet but with no luck, thus this post.

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Try prime-select nvidia or prime-select Intel, see if it works with either one specifically

Comment: The external monitor, as you already found out, only work with Nvidia. You now have a problem with the Nvidia driver because it failed to compile with the new non standard kernel. Try booting with a previous kernel (the advice in the comment above isn't applicable).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've swicthed back to 5.13.0-23-generic and (later) to 5.13.0-22-generic but nothing changed :(

Comment: @Shanteva - that was one of the first things I've done before posting this issue. Obviously didn't helped.

Comment: When running the standard kernel open Additional Drivers. Check if the recommended driver is installed and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I'm running kernel 5.13.0-22-generic.
Additional Drivers shows that driver 495 is in use but driver seams to be still corrupted.

Comment: Nvidia still recommends 470 for your card.

Comment: nothing changed after switching to nvidia-driver-470 + kernel 5.13.0-22

Comment: have you blacklisted nouveau? Also make sure dkms is installed :shrug:

Comment: @Shanteva
dkms status output:

nvidia, 470.86: added

I've blacklisted noveau and restarted system.

No improvment :(

Comment: @Kragh Hey! Wait... You're using a system76 kernel, aren't you? If you're on a system76 hardware then only use that kernel. Are you using Pop!_OS? That kernel was specially designed for Pop!_OS hardware with some advanced drivers. Those advanced drivers are messing up with your system. Can you provide a little more details? Something like what commands did you use to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: nope. I'm not using system76. I'm on vanilla Ubuntu 21 and Dell laptop